# Partially Displaying Checkbox Options Based on Tab

Tags: channel-entries, control-panel, fieldtype, entries

This is somewhat a follow on question to [Grouping Channel Fields](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/grouping-channel-fields)

Say I have a checkbox field that has 100 options. I'd like to show about 20 options only when in a certain tab, then the complete 100 when in a different tab. Basically, the 20 options are the most common choices. Having the 100 options fully displayed in another tab gives the user the option to select the not so common choices, if needed.

Any way to do this (or something like this)? It wont be good if I show 100 options -- especially since I have several checkbox fields like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fields are generally not interlinked and, to be honest, the workflow you're describing doesn't sound ideal anyway. If you're getting to the point where you have so many options to select from that the UI is getting unwieldy then, rather than splitting the data into different sets, I'd have thought the best approach would be to switch to a revised UI that lets users more easily filter through available options.

The [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) JS plugin is excellent for this sort of thing - take a look at the Multiple Select UI. I've only ever used it on the frontend but there is a free [Chosen Selects](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/chosen-selects) EE fieldtype which you might want to try out.